# Distance between every pair of nodes in a tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

Given A Tree. How to find distance between every pair of nodes in tree without using 2D matrix of size n*n. I know solution of O(n^2) complexity .

Comment: If the output is (v1,v2,distance) for each v1,v2 - you cannot do better then O(n^2), since **the output size itself is O(n^2)**. Please elaborate what the expected output should be. A simple example will be also great.

Comment: This might be useful [All pair shortest path in Trees](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59680/all-pairs-shortest-paths-in-trees)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already mentioned in comment, assuming that the output should be `(v1,v2,distance)` for every pair of vertices `v1,v2` in your tree - note that there are `n*(n-1)` pairs of such vertices. Since `n*(n-1)` is in `O(n^2)` - and it is the size of the output, **it cannot be done better then `O(n^2)`**, so your algorithm is optimal, in terms of big O notation.

Comment: What about space complexity?.. can you do it in less than O(n^2) Space?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to be able to answer queries of form `distance(u, v)` fast enough with fast preprocessing, you may use [LCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor). LCA, or lowest common ancestor, of two vertices in a rooted tree is a vertex which is an ancestor of both of them and which is the lowest among all of theirs common ancestors. There is a not very complex algorithm to find `LCA(u, v)` in logarithmic time with `n log n` preprocessing time. I can describe it if it is needed.

So, your problem may be solved as following. First, fix a root of your tree. Then make an above mentioned preprocessing to be able to find LCA. Then, supposing `h[v]` is a distance from `v` to the root (can be precomputed in linear time for all vertices) then `distance(u, v) = h[u] + h[v] - 2 * h[LCA(u, v)]`.

Comment: could u please provide link or explain with pseudo code explaining above concept

Comment: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/

Comment: This link may also be helpful: [LCA](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/lca.html)